# Remove possible double encoding from Unicode

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I am using a Python 2.7 based API to connect to a third party software. Some of the methods return broken UTF-8 encoding. I don't believe it's related to Python 2.7 handling of Unicode on my end because some the API methods return correct UTF-8 strings.

For example:

The API returns: `┼íe┼íir`
instead of: `šešir`

The API returns: `─îeki─ç`
instead of: `Čekić`

I thought it could be double encoding of some sort, but attempts to correct the strings went nowhere. I can load any test string on the third party software side. Is there a technique that would allow me to figure out what's going on with the encoding by entering judiciously crafted strings?

Comment: You are using Python 2.7, so are those byte strings being printed in a Windows command prompt?  The characters are UTF-8 bytes displayed as CP437 encoding, which is the default encoding of the U.S. Windows command prompt.  If they are byte strings, type `chcp 1252` at the command prompt and in Python decode them with `.decode('utf8')` and print the Unicode string result.

Comment: That was a valuable clue. The encoding was indeed CP437. Thank you.